# how to trigger on specific section on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

What I am trying to do is, In The parallax section images when reaching their original position when the container in which they are in is in the middle of the screen (vertically).

I just need to make the images stop when they get to the topmost position. So, what I am trying to do is freeze the parallax effect on that section by applying this codes. But, they do not seem to be working.

I have added ID to 2 sections no. 1 ID is `#parallax-d-active` which I have added to the above section of parallax section and no. 2 ID is `#parallax-active` which is the parallax section itself.

I don't know how to make it happen. Please, Help.

Thank You in Advance.

This is a test site I have set up.

http://salehahmad.com/test/parallax/

this is the CSS code:

```
.card-img-top.active {
   background-position: 50% 0!important;
}
```

this is the js code I am using.

```
$('#parallax-active').waypoint(function() {
   $(".card-img-top").addClass("active");  
}, { offset: 101 });


$('#parallax-d-active').waypoint(function() {
    $(".card-img-top").removeClass("active");
}, { offset: 101 });
```

Comment: There is many parallax plugins out there, I believe that with this one https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax you can easily apply what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But, what I need is on scroll events for this parallax. This one works on mouse hover.